# Postgres Dockerfile exploration - VOLUME statement usage

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am looking at sample dockerfile to see how VOLUME is used , I come across the following lines from - https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template

```
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data
# this 777 will be replaced by 700 at runtime (allows semi-arbitrary "--user" values)
RUN mkdir -p "$PGDATA" && chown -R postgres:postgres "$PGDATA" && chmod 777 "$PGDATA"
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

What is the purpose of using a volume here , here is my understanding - please confirm

1. Create directory  pointed by $PGDATA in image file system.
2. Map it with the VOLUME so that any content created later as part of populating the content thorough docker-entrypont.sh by exposing a predefined directory that could be used by the container.

What if the VOLUME instr is not defined ? It might more laborious for someone to figure out where to keep custom changes unless VOLUME is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume is define here, so when you start a container ( out of this image ) a new anonymous volume is created.

The volume will hold your sensible data in this regard, so this is all you need to "persist" during normal/soft docker image lifecycled.

Usually when the maintainers of docker images are already aware where the data, which will be sensible to keep, is located ( like here ) there will decorate the folder using `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile. This will, as mentioned, create a anon-volume during  runtime but also makes you aware ( using `docker inspect` or reading the Dockerfile ) where volumes for persistence are located.

In production you usually will used a named volume / path mount in your docker-compose file mounted to this very folder

`docker-compose.yml` as named volume

```yaml
volumes:
  mydbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

`docker-compose.yml` as path

```yaml
volumes:
  ./local/path/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

There are actually cons in defining such `VOLUME` definitions in the Dockerfile, which i will not elaborate here, but the main reason is "lifetime".

Having no `VOLUME` in the `Dockerfile` and running

```
docker-compose up -d
# do something, manipulate the data
docker-compose down

# all your data would be lost when starting again
docker-compose up -d
```

Would remove not only the running container, but all your DB data, which might not what you intended ( you just wanted to recreated the container ).

With `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile, the anon-volume would be persisted even over `docker-compose down`

Comment: I understood "decorating" sensible directory with "VOLUME" makes sense as this is useful for documenting / hinting to someone using this image to aware that this directory (/var/lib/postgresql/data) needed to be mounted .  Otherwise, they need to go through entire Dockerfile to figure out this. Am I right ?

Comment: However, i think specifying "VOLUME" not necessarily create the volume  like "EXPOSE" not necessarily exposes the ports- It merely functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.. Am I right ?

Comment: If you specify `VOLUME`, an anonymous volume will always be created at runtime, but this isn't necessarily obvious to an operator.  The most obvious impacts of this are that you can't make any future modifications to that directory tree in the Dockerfile, and you'll potentially leak space in a `docker run; docker rm` sequence if you don't clean up the volumes.

Comment: `VOLUME` will create a anon volume, even if you "overmount it" ( one of the flaws ) - so there is one in any way.  On the contrary `EXPOSE` is more "documentation" alike let's call it meta data for edge routers like Traefik or similar.